# how to access Debug breakpoint registers on Cortex A9

Tags: debugging, arm, embedded, breakpoints, bare-metal

When I try to access the debug breakpoint registers via CP14 on a dual core cortex a9 MP processor, I get "undefined instruction" exception.
I guess I have an issue with authorization but can't find what to do.
Is it possible that for some implementation of the Cortex A9 IP, these accesses are denied by some hardware configuration ?

My plan is to use the hardware feature of Coresight to be able to trig on some Data access on a given variable in bare metal. The same that I do via a jtag probe but without any specific hardware attached to the processor.

Comment: What mode are you in when you try to make the access, for starters? As always, if we don't know exactly what you're doing, we can't tell which part of it you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I am in secure supervisor mode, sorry for not having been more specific

Comment: Having finally found section C6.6.2 of the [ARMv7 ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html), the debug architecture specifies more possible controls on CP14 that I can even comprehend. Not sure this is easily answerable at all :/